# creating a variable in function - multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading

could you please help me?

I have a function 'f' in Java. The function works in multithreading environment

```
f() {

SomeObject someO = new SomeObject();


  function1(someO);
  .
  .
  .
  function7(someO);

}
```

The problem: first thread enters into the function 'f' and creates new instance of SomeObject then calls function1, function2 ect. An instant later second thread enters into the method and creates new instnce of SomeObject when the first thread is in function4. The question is which instance of SomeObject will be processing by first thread in the rest of function 5, 6, 7 ?

Comment: The invocations from the two different threads will create two different instances, assign them to two different local variables and each will be passed to each of the functions. What do you think will happen that is different than that and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thread has its instance of SomeObject (aka some0) as a local variable, therefore it is local to that stackframe and hence to that thread. It will only be able to reference that instance of some0.

Any other thread calling f() will create a different instance, also named some0, and only be able to reference that copy of it.

These are the rules for a local variable. If some0 were an instance variable -- i.e., declared outside f() -- then that variable could be referenced by different threads if they called f() on the same instance of whatever class holds the definition of f().

Those are the rules -- here's a more complete explanation.

Local variables are declared on the stack; that means that, for any variables declared within a method, there is space for their references in a 'stack frame' for that invocation of that method. Each time a method is invoked, there is space on the stack allocated for all the local variables in the method, and therefore their references are separate from any other invocation of that method. So if a different thread invokes the method, it gets a different stack frame for the local variables.

The same thing happens in a recursive procedure, i.e., if f() were to call itself. The local variable references would still be separate for each invocation of f(), i.e., each recursive call would have its own copy of them. Otherwise it would be very difficult to use recursion at all.

Comment: It's also important to note that this behavior is guaranteed by the Java language specification.  Normally this is a benefit: because local variables are created anew with each invocation of a method, they are *thread safe* since they share no memory with other invocations.  This is often used in concurrent programming as a guarantee that local variable are safe until published where other threads can see them.

Answer (score 0):

First thread will process first instance of SomeObject.
Every Thread creates its own stack. and whatever methods it is calling and whatever local objects it is creating, will live in that stack and these objects are not affected by other thread. So in your case thread 1 one processing is not going to affect by thread 2 processing.